# Spark unionByName and dropping noncommon columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Say I have the following code

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], ["col0", "col1", "col2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[4, 5, 6,7]], ["col1", "col2", "col0","col3"])
df1.unionByName(df2).show()
```

I want this to return

```
+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   6|   4|   5|
+----+----+----+
```

Even using `df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True).show()` results in

```
+----+----+----+----+                                                           
|col0|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|null|
|   6|   4|   5|   7|
+----+----+----+----+
```

But I dont want any nulls. I want the column dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the columns from df2 before joining:

```
common_cols = [i for i in df1.columns if i in df2.columns]
result = df1.select(common_cols).unionByName(df2.select(common_cols))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this thats backwards compatible. When I process my Df joins I won't know which one is df1 or df2